# PHP- Query MySQLi results nearest a given number

Tags: php

I am trying to search for an invoice by the amount. So, I would like to search all invoices +/- 10% of the amount searched, and order by the result closest to the given number:

```
$search = 100.00
$lower = $search * 0.9; // 90
$higher = $search * 1.1 // 110

$results = $db->select("SELECT ID from `invoices` WHERE Amount >= `$lower` && Amount >= `$higher`");
```

So, I am not sure how to order these. Let's say this query gives me the following results:

```
108, 99, 100, 103, 92
```

I want to order the results, starting with the actual number searched (since it's an exact match), and working out from there, so:

```
100, 99, 103, 92, 108
```

Comment: `Amount >= $lower && Amount >= $higher`? really? Maybe `Amount <= $higher`?

Comment: use the [between](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp) clause to get the values between two numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```php
$search = 100.00
$lower = $search * 0.9; // 90
$higher = $search * 1.1 // 110

$results = $db->select("SELECT ID from `invoices`
    WHERE Amount >= `$lower` && Amount <= `$higher`
    ORDER BY ABS(Amount - $search)
");
```

The ABS function returns the absolute value of its argument (=> it basically removes the minus from negative numbers). Therefore `ABS(Amount - $search)` returns the distance from the `$search` value.

Besides that you should consider using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). Otherwise your application could be vulnerable to sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this as follows:

```
$search = 100.00
$deviation = 0.10;

$results = $db->select("
    SELECT ID, Amount, ABS(1 - Amount/$search) deviation
    FROM   invoices
    WHERE  ABS(1 - Amount/$search) <= $deviation
    ORDER  BY ABS(1 - Amount/$search)
");
```

Output is:

```
+----+--------+-----------+
| id | Amount | deviation |
+----+--------+-----------+
| 3  |   100  |    0      | 
| 2  |    99  |    0.01   | 
| 4  |   103  |    0.03   |
| 1  |   108  |    0.08   |
| 5  |    92  |    0.08   |
+----+--------+-----------+
```

Here is an [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86682b/3)

This way you let SQL calculate the deviation, by dividing the actual amount by the "perfect" amount (*$search*). This will be 1 for a perfect match. By subtracting this from 1, the perfect match is represented by the value 0. Any deviation is non-zero. By taking the absolute value of that, you get the exact deviation as a fractional number (representing a percentage), like for example 0.02 (which is 2%).

By comparing this deviation to a given maximum deviation (*$deviation*), you get what you need. Of course, ordering is then easily done on this calculated deviation.